# Difference in meaning of "congratulation" and "congratulations"

Tags: differences, grammatical-number, nouns

What is the difference between *congratulation* and *congratulations*?

Answer (score 1):

From NOAD:

> **congratulation** |kənˌgra ch əˈlā sh ən; -ˌgrajə-|
>   *noun*
>   an expression of praise for an achievement or good wishes on a special occasion; the act of congratulating : *he began pumping the hand of his son in 
>   congratulation*.
>   • ( **congratulations**) words expressing congratulation : *our congratulations to the winners* | [as exclam. ] *congratulations on a job well done!*

You make the call.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to articulate the difference between them.

When you are speaking *about* the act of praise, a single act of praise is a congratulation, multiple is -s. You can almost always use the plural form and sound perfectly normal.

When you wish to praise someone:

I congratulate you. (much more formal, can easily sound distant or impersonal)

You have my congratulations. Shortened: Congratulations! or Congratulations on your wedding! (always plural in shortened forms seemingly expressing multiple praises, explanation for what the congratulation is for only necessary when it isn't clear)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is very subtle :

- "congratulation" is congratulating, that is having some joy, some pleasure, perhaps by yourself and even secretly, for instance because you have won at the lottery ;
- congratulations" are the expression of that, for instance to a newly married couple.

The word comes from Latin *congratulatio*, with exactly the same meaning.

Comment: OED says your first sense, "Grateful and glad acknowledgement on one's own behalf, rejoicing" is obsolete. I suppose *self-congratulation* might not be, but that's related to your second sense.